# Pagination (React Bootstrap) does not work correct on Next JS

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

I have a problem with Pagination. The problem is that, there is no disable or  active button due to `scss`. I add react bootstrap styles only one component. If I add `app.scss` there is no problem and everything works. What do you suggest me for solution?

Look. `page-link` does not have `disable` attribute. It happens when I added `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` into `Pagination` component.
[image]

add after adding `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"` in `app.scss`

[image]

My codes

Parent element

```
  <div className="pages">
        <Paginate
          count={totalElements}
          recordSize={20}
          currentPage={page}
          click={(page) => {
            console.log(page);
            getAllCoach(page);
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

Paginate (child) component

```
import Pagination from "react-bootstrap/Pagination";

function Paginate(props) {
  const amountPages = Math.ceil(props.count / props.recordSize);
  let next = props.currentPage + 1;
  let prev = props.currentPage - 1;

  return amountPages > 1 ? (
    <div className="pagination-block flex-vertical-center">
      <Pagination>
        <Pagination.Prev
          disabled={props.currentPage === 1 ? true : false}
          onClick={() => {
            props.click(props.currentPage - 1);
          }}
        />
        {props.currentPage !== 1 ? (
          <Pagination.Item
            active={1 === props.currentPage}
            onClick={() => {
              props.click(1);
            }}
          >
            1
          </Pagination.Item>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {prev - 1 > 1 ? <Pagination.Ellipsis /> : ""}
        {props.currentPage !== 1 && prev !== 1 ? (
          <Pagination.Item
            active={props.currentPage === prev}
            onClick={() => {
              props.click(prev);
            }}
          >
            {prev}
          </Pagination.Item>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <Pagination.Item
          active={props.currentPage}
          onClick={() => {
            props.click(props.currentPage);
          }}
        >
          {props.currentPage}
        </Pagination.Item>
        {props.currentPage !== amountPages && next !== amountPages ? (
          <Pagination.Item
            active={props.currentPage + 1 === props.currentPage}
            onClick={() => {
              props.click(props.currentPage + 1);
            }}
          >
            {props.currentPage + 1}
          </Pagination.Item>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {next + 1 < amountPages ? <Pagination.Ellipsis /> : ""}
        {props.currentPage !== amountPages ? (
          <Pagination.Item
            active={amountPages === props.currentPage}
            onClick={() => {
              props.click(amountPages);
            }}
          >
            {amountPages}
          </Pagination.Item>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <Pagination.Next
          disabled={props.currentPage === amountPages ? true : false}
          onClick={() => {
            props.click(props.currentPage + 1);
          }}
        />
      </Pagination>
    </div>
  ) : (
    ""
  );
}
```

Pagination.scss

```
.pages {
  margin-top: 16px;
  @include flexBox(center, center);
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  .pagination-block {
    .pagination {
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0;
    }
  }
}
```